# How to wait a file for certain seconds

Tags: c#, .net

How to wait a file for 90 seconds ,if it didnot create within 90 seconds we should make timeout and exit the function.If it creates within this time of 90 seconds it should return as true

I did following code with failure

```
private bool Wait(string filePath, int maxSecs, ref string errDesc)
    {
        System.DateTime timeNow = System.DateTime.Now;
        bool timeOut = false;
        try
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                return true;
            System.DateTime currentdatetime = System.DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan diff = currentdatetime - timeNow;
            //timeOut = Math.Abs(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, timeNow, System.DateTime.Now)) >= maxSecs;

            if (timeOut)
            {
                errDesc = "File creation failed";
                return false;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errDesc = ex.Message;
        }
        return timeOut;
    }
```

Comment: The main issue you need is to detect file creation asynchronously. You can use `FileSystemWatcher` to do this. See marked duplicate. The other parts include subscribing to the event and setting a `TaskCompletionSource` value when your event handler is called. You then can implement an asynchronous timeout using `Task.Delay()` or `CancellationTokenSource` (which can be configured to cancel automatically after a timeout). The async approach is not strictly necessary but IMHO better, and will avoid your blocking any important threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
TimeSpan diff = currentdatetime - timeNow;
timeOut = diff.Seconds > maxSecs;

if (timeOut) 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a for-loop waiting 2 seconds 45 times. If within this period the file is created, you return "true" from inside the loop. Just after the loop you put a "return false". No error catching needed imo.